# How to take many samples of 10 from a large list, without replacement overall

Tags: r, sample

I've got a large set of data (20,000 data points), from which I want to take repeated samples of 10 data points. However, once I've picked those 10 data points, I want them to not be picked again.

I've tried using the `sample` function, but it doesn't seem to have an option to sample without replacement over multiple calls of the function. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could call sample once on the entire data set to permute it.  Then when you want to get a sample you could grab the first 10.  If you want another sample grab the next 10.  So on and so forth.

Answer (score 10):

Dason's thought, implemented in R:

```
sample <- split(sample(datapoints), rep(1:(length(datapoints)/10+1), each=10))
sample[[13]] # the thirteenth sample
```

Comment: (+1) Really neat R code. Of note, it will not work if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @chl Thanks!  But I think it will work. The task was to give samples of size 10 from a set of datapoints. Assume n = length(datapoints). The code gives the maximum number (n %/% 10) of such samples. The first corner case is n<10 (anyway ruled out in the problem statement by describing the dataset as 'large', i.e. n>10). In that case you get the datapoints back and a warning (not an error). The second corner case is if there are dangling elements (when n %% 10 != 0). Then you get as many samples as possible and a warning (not an error). Odd n situations are subsumed in one of these two cases.

Comment: It seems the first element of the list is of length 11, not 10, and `sum(unlist(lapply(sample, length)))` return the length of `datapoints` (which I set to 1001).

Comment: @chl Damn! You're quite right.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
x <- rnorm(20000)
x.copy <- x
samples <- list()
i <- 1
while (length(x) >= 10){
    tmp <- sample(x, 10)
    samples[[i]] <- tmp
    i <- i+1
    x <- x[-match(tmp, x)]
}

table(unlist(samples) %in% x.copy)
```

However, I don't think that's the most elegant solution...

Answer (score 1):

@conjugateprior Your answer is going in the right direction. But at least for my current R-version 3.4.3, it does not work. However with some tweaking it works:

```
mysample<-split(sample(length(datapoints)), 1:10)
mysample[[9]] ## the ninth sample
```

Since I cant comment yet I chose to answer here.