# sample of arbitrary length from large list without replacement

Tags: r, sampling

I'm interested in sampling a large dataset in nonconsecutive-record sequences of arbitrary length without overlap. I know from

[How to take many samples of 10 from a large list, without replacement overall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/how-to-take-many-samples-of-10-from-a-large-list-without-replacement-overall)

how to do it if the sequence length is fixed (at 10 in that example), via

```
sample <- split(sample(datapoints), rep(1:(length(datapoints)/10+1), each=10))
```

How do I generalize this to emit uniformly-distributed sized samplings, not just sequences of 10?

Furthermore, can I specify that I want `N` such sequences?

---

For example, suppose I have the sequence `d <- 1:20` and permute it via `sample(d, 20, replace = F)` to obtain another permuted sequence. Now I want to extract arbitrarily sized subsequences of this permuted sequence, say `d1 <- c(1,5,4,15,3)`, `d2<- c(18,7,12,11,19,16,10,8,14,17, 20, 13)`, `d3 <- c(9,2,6)` in a quick manner as in the example. My dataset is large, and I'd like to simply sample it once, and then split it without any length constraint as in the post I cite.

Comment: Are you familiar with the binomial distribution.  You can randomly draw from a binomial to decide sample length and which chunks to draw.

Comment: Arbitrarily sized as in e.g. 25 instead of 10?

Comment: A uniform distribution of sizes.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The sampling has to be exhaustive, i.e. include each datapoint exactly once.

Comment: You need some process to decide your sample length and which data to sample. If you would like these things to not be fixed but rather allow them to vary randomly you must draw them from a descrete probability distribution.  The binomial distribution is a good place to start

Comment: If you sample without replacement you just redefine the binomial to be over the leftover data after each draw.

Comment: When you say chunks of arbitrary length, do you want these chunks to contain consecutive records from your data set, or each to be chosen at random from the entire data set? ("Chunks of length..." sounds rather like you mean a consecutive run, though I don't think this is what you intend, judging from the rest of the question talking about "sampling".)

Comment: Nonconsecutive records, you're right. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Zachary: I'll try, but I'm trying to avoid the implicit `for` loop

Comment: Basically, how do you randomly subset a single reshuffling of indices in one go?

Comment: n=length(data); nn=sample(1:n,n,replace=FALSE); rand.start=sample(1:(n-1),1); rand.end=sample((rand.start+1):n,1); 
rand.samp=data[nn[rand.start:rand.end]]; # is that what you mean?

Comment: It's close. Suppose I create a while loop on this for `n` by setting and create a list for `rand.samp` that contains all the nonoverlapping, unequal length subsequences. Then you can verify `hist(unlist(rand.samp))` is heavily skewed to short sequences. How can I make the distribution of sequence lengths uniform?

Comment: After reading several times through the question and comments I still have no idea what you are asking. Because your usage of terms appears to be inconsistent with their standard meanings, I don't know what you mean by "sample"--it sounds like it could be a permutation, or maybe not--nor by "nonconsecutive-record", nor even by "sequence" or "arbitrary length"! Could you perhaps illustrate the input and desired output for a small example?

Comment: Any ambiguity is my fault. Let me try again: Ok, suppose I have the sequence d <- 1:20 and permute it via sample(d, 20, replace = F) to obtain another permuted sequence. Now I want to extract arbitrarily sized subsequences of this permuted sequence, say d1 <- c(1,5,4,15,3), d2<- c(18,7,12,11,19,16,10,8,14,17, 20, 13), d3 <- c(9,2,6) in a quick manner as in the example. My dataset is large, and I'd like to simply sample it once, and then split it without any length constraint as in the post I cite. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple answer based on Zachary's comment. However, for larger datasets (`dim(data1)[1]`) it isn't efficient and plus it doesn't simply permute the dataset once via `sample` and then `split` it into arbitrarily sized samples, which was the elegant logic of the original post I cited above.

```
#data1 <- 1:14e6
#data <- sample(data1, length(data1), replace = F) #not necessary
data <- 1:14e6
K <- 0
rand.samp <- NULL
while(dim(as.matrix(data))[1] != 0) {
K <- 1 + K
n=length(data);
nn=sample(1:n,n,replace=FALSE);
rand.start=sample(1:(n-1),1);
rand.end=sample((rand.start+1):n,1);
rand.samp[[K]]=data[nn[rand.start:rand.end]];
data <- setdiff( data, unlist(rand.samp))
print(dim(as.matrix(data))[1])
                                    }
```

## desired output is this list

```
rand.samp
```

## histogram of random sequence lengths

```
hist(log10(unlist(lapply(rand.samp, length))), breaks = 100)
```